# Seg. fault in Multithreaded UDP server

Tags: c++, multithreading, sockets

**Background:**

I have a UDP server that can process clients' requests concurrently. Each client sends two datagrams to the server.

1. First datagram (Type - 1, Client num)
2. Second datagram (Type - 2, Client num)

To process all clients concurrently, I initially create a fixed number of server threads and one global UDP socket bound to a known port/address. Then each thread starts to run wherein they block on recvfrom() call on the same global socket. Whichever thread receives a datagram first checks 
the type. If it is type 1, it generates a "special" number for the client num it received and stores it. It it is type 2, it sends back the stored "special" number for that client.

**Server program:**

```
#define SIZE 1024

int status;
int tnum;
int i;
vector<pthread_t> tid;
struct sockaddr_in server_sock_addr;
const char *server_addr = "127.0.0.1";
int sock;
int reuse = 1;
socklen_t addr_len = sizeof(sockaddr_in);
unordered_map<int, int> dic;

void report(int status){
    if(status < 0){
        perror("Error");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}

void* server_func(void *arg){
    int bytes;
    char *buf = (char*)malloc(SIZE);
    struct sockaddr_in client_sock_addr;
    int type;
    int num;

    while(1){
        bytes = recvfrom(sock, buf, SIZE, 0, (sockaddr*)&client_sock_addr, &addr_len);
        cout<<bytes<<endl;
        report(bytes);
        memmove(&type, buf, sizeof(int));
        memmove(&num, buf + sizeof(int), sizeof(int));
        if(type == 1){
            dic[num] = num * 1000;
        }
        else if(type == 2){
            while(dic.find(num) == dic.end()){
            };
            memset(buf, 0, SIZE);
            memmove(buf, &dic[num], sizeof(int));
            status = sendto(sock, buf, sizeof(int), 0, (sockaddr*)&client_sock_addr, addr_len);
            report(status);
            cout<<"Mapped number is "<<num<<" - "<<dic[num]<<endl;
        }
        else{
            report(-1);
        }
    }
    free(buf);
}

int main() {

    cout<<"-------------------------------------------"<<endl;
    cout<<"SERVER STARTED on port 5000"<<endl;
    cout<<"-------------------------------------------"<<endl;
    tnum = 4;
    sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP);
    bzero((char*)&server_sock_addr, sizeof(server_sock_addr));
    server_sock_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server_sock_addr.sin_port = htons(5000);
    inet_aton(server_addr, &server_sock_addr.sin_addr);
    setsockopt(sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &reuse, sizeof(int));
    status = bind(sock, (struct sockaddr*)&server_sock_addr, sizeof(server_sock_addr));
    report(status);
    tid.resize(tnum);
    dic.clear();
    for (i = 0; i < tnum; i++) {
        status = pthread_create(&tid[i], NULL, server_func, NULL);
        report(status);
    }
    for (i = 0; i < tnum; i++) {
        pthread_join(tid[i], NULL);
    }   
    close(sock);
    return 0;
}
```

**Client program**

```
#define SIZE 1024

int num;
int i;
vector<pthread_t> tid;
vector<int> client_num;
const char *server_addr = "127.0.0.1";
socklen_t addr_len = sizeof(sockaddr_in);

void report(int status){
    if(status < 0){
        perror("Error");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}

void* client_func(void *arg){
    struct sockaddr_in server_sock_addr;
    int cnum = *((int*)arg);
    char *buf = (char*)malloc(SIZE);
    int type;
    int sock;
    int bytes;
    int status;
    int res;

    sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP);
    bzero((char*)&server_sock_addr, sizeof(server_sock_addr));
    server_sock_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server_sock_addr.sin_port = htons(5000);
    status = inet_aton(server_addr, &server_sock_addr.sin_addr);
    report(status);

    type = 1;
    memset(buf, 0, SIZE);
    memmove(buf, &type, sizeof(int));
    memmove(buf + sizeof(int), &cnum, sizeof(int));
    status = sendto(sock, buf, 2 * sizeof(int), 0, (sockaddr*)&server_sock_addr, addr_len);
    report(status);
    type = 2;
    memset(buf, 0, SIZE);
    memmove(buf, &type, sizeof(int));
    memmove(buf + sizeof(int), &cnum, sizeof(int));
    status = sendto(sock, buf, 2 * sizeof(int), 0, (sockaddr*)&server_sock_addr, addr_len);
    report(status);
    bytes = recvfrom(sock, buf, SIZE, 0, (sockaddr*)&server_sock_addr, &addr_len);
    report(bytes);
    memcpy(&res, buf, sizeof(int));
    cout<<"Mapped number from the server for Client - "<<cnum<<" is "<<res<<endl;
    free(buf);
    close(sock);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int status;

    if(argc < 2){
        cout<<"Enter number of threads"<<endl;
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    num = atoi(argv[1]);
    tid.resize(num);
    client_num.resize(num);
    for (i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        client_num[i] = i+1;
        status = pthread_create(&tid[i], NULL, client_func, &client_num[i]);
    }
    for (i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        pthread_join(tid[i],NULL);
    }
    cout << "Requested duration has ended. Finishing the program." << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

**Problem I am facing:**

When 500 clients send datagrams concurrently, **the server works as expected only when I include some kind of COUT statement after the recvfrom() call(First line in while(1) loop)**. If I delete that cout statement, it gives Segmentation fault because the server gets stuck on the while() loop to check whether an item exists or not. `while(dic.find(num) == dic.end()){};`. I am not able to figure out the reason for this problem. Please provide me your suggestions.

Thanks.

**EDIT:**

- Having a mutex lock on "dic" data-structure(while writing it) solves the problem(I do not need to use "cout" anymore), but I want to confirm whether this is absolutely the correct fix and want to learn anyother subtle points that I could out of this program, because I'd building a much bigger version of this program soon with lots of global datastructures to be shared by all threads

Comment: `unordered_map`, like all other standard C++ containers, is not thread safe. By modifying `dic` from multiple threads with no synchronization whatsoever, your program exhibits undefined behavior.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik But I need a global datastructure that is accessible to all threads.  Could you pls tell what possible modification can I do to make it work irrespective of that "cout" statement? Any other datastructure?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik: Having a mutex lock on that `dic` would solve the problem? I actually tried and the server worked fine, but I wanted to confirm this and learn anyother subtle points out of this program, since I'd  building a much bigger version of this program soon with lots of global datastructures to be shared by threads .

Comment: A mutex around accesses to `dic` (and whatever other shared state you plan to use) is certainly a necessary condition for this design to work.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik: Do you think it is necessary to lock a global data-structure even during read process? I mean lock the global data only during writing it?

Comment: There must not be two simultaneous writes, nor a simultaneous read and write. To protect against the latter, it's generally necessary to lock for reads, too, not just writes.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik  Thanks. So lock during both reads and writes!. but please clarify one more doubt. The thing is that a thread would be writing on a vector or map for  a particular client_num(here "key' = "client_num") and the thread that wants to read data for this client_num would wait in a loop, so I do not see any data race condition occuring here, since threads wont be writing on the "same key" because client_num is going to be unique. Excuse me for troubling you with doubts but I'd like to know the subtle point here.

Comment: @user_tn It's necessary because different keys in the same map still share some stuff, like the storage memory allocation and size variable which could be modified if a new key is created, etc.etc.

Comment: Btw., as you know, reads only need to be locked because of the possibility of writes from elsewhere. Maybe you want to use a reader-writer-lock, it allows either one writer or multiple readers at the same time, contrary to a normal mutex where only one thing can have the lock independent of it's type. C++14 has std::shared_mutex which can do that (without it, there are other implementations on the net)

Comment: @deviantfan: Thanks for your reply. Please correct me if I am wrong. Say, I just use an array of predefined size(say 10000) and store client data according to the array index(array index here indicating client_num), I won't be needing the mutex lock on this array, right? Since client_num is mapped to array index for my program. BTW I tried using INT array without using locks and the server worked fine.

Comment: @user_tn Correct. With a raw array of elements, where the single element size is a multiple of the processors native word size, and a guarentee that different threads won't ever access the same element (and the single array elements are not class objects sharing some common data), you don't need a lock. (But remember that, in general, "working fine now" doesn't mean that it will work fine everywhere anytime. Don't rely on something being ok just because it works)

Comment: You can read and write individual values concurrently, as long as no thread writes a given value while another thread reads or writes that same value. However, you don't merely read or write a value in the map - you insert a new key. That affects all keys. You can't, say, `find()` in one thread while the other `insert()`s.

Comment: @deviantfan The standard guarantees that different array elements are distinct "memory locations" (term of art in the standard), and can be accessed by multiple threads independently of each other. They don't need to be in any way related to "native word size" - in fact, no such concept exists in the standard. For example, it's perfectly OK to concurrently access individual elements of an array of `char`s.